# background color after distortion - imagemagick

Tags: imagemagick, imagemagick-convert

I am trying to render a text and then apply perspective transformation to that image using imagemagick convert command .

I am trying to use the following command :

`convert a.jpg -matte -distort Perspective-Projection '1.0,0.25,0.0,0.0,1,0.0,0.007,0' +repage ' a_new.jpg`

The problem is that the resulting image have black background but instead I want it be of same color as that of text background ans same is the case with the color of border . Also , 
the resulting text some times get trimmed , but I want the text content to be preserved . I tried out various combinations of commands but didn't produced the desired result .

Comment: Can you post your original image and also some indication of how it is supposed to look afterwards please? In the meantime, maybe try adding `-virtual-pixel black`

Comment: @MarkSetchell : here is the final image after some above mentioned operations (http://i.imgur.com/4mT2Y3i.png).I want the white part to be of the same color as background . Also , I want the whole text content instead of the cropped text content .